# Count 0 if there is no existing record

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database with 2 tables.

1. Projects

```html
+--------------+--------+
| project_name | Active |
+--------------+--------+
| A            | Yes    |
| B            | No     |
| C            | Yes    |
| D            | Yes    |
+--------------+--------+
```

2. form-site_safety_inspection

```html
+---------+-----------------+------------------------------+
| project | inspection_date |      Type_of_Inspection      |
+---------+-----------------+------------------------------+
| A       | 2019-08-20      | Supervisor Weekly Inspection |
| D       | 2019-08-20      | Supervisor Weekly Inspection |
| D       | 2019-08-21      | Supervisor Weekly Inspection |
| A       | 2019-08-22      | Supervisor Weekly Inspection |
+---------+-----------------+------------------------------+
```

`project_name` from Projects table = `project` from form-site_safety_inspection table.

New rows are added to form-site_safety_inspection regularly. On a weekly basis I need to count how many rows were added to form-site_safety_inspection by active projects. If there are no rows added by an active project that week, I need to count 0.

So far I coded a query which counts rows in form-site_safety_inspection added by active projects. I'm missing the part of the code which shows a count of 0 if there are no rows submitted by an active project.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), project

FROM form-site_safety_inspection

LEFT JOIN projects ON form-site_safety_inspection.project = Projects.project_name

WHERE form-site_safety_inspection.Type_of_Inspection= "Supervisor Weekly Inspection"

AND Projects.Active = "Yes"

AND year(inspection_date) = year(curdate())

AND month(inspection_date) = month(curdate())

AND week(inspection_date) = week(curdate())

GROUP BY form-site_safety_inspection.project

ORDER BY form-site_safety_inspection.project
```

Using the above code I get the result:

```html
+----------+---------+
| COUNT(*) | project |
+----------+---------+
|        2 | A       |
|        2 | D       |
+----------+---------+
```

I'm looking for the following result:

```html
+----------+---------+
| COUNT(*) | project |
+----------+---------+
|        2 | A       |
|        0 | C       |
|        2 | D       |
+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your left join approach is correct, except that the restrictions on the date need to appear in the `ON` clause of the join, rather than in the `WHERE` clause, because you don't want them to filter off any projects.  Note that the restriction on `Active` *can* appear in the `WHERE` clause, because you don't want to see any inactive projects.

```
SELECT
    p.project_name,
    COUNT(f.project) AS cnt
FROM Projects p
LEFT JOIN `form-site_safety_inspection` f
    ON p.project_name = f.project AND
    YEARWEEK(inspection_date, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
WHERE
    p.Active = 'Yes'
GROUP BY
    p.project_name;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: btw why is his answer not giving the same result? just wondering... new to sql

Comment: @Kushan I couldn't even answer my own question until I setup the demo.  The problem is that his restrictions on the date appears in the `WHERE` clause, which is causing certain projects to be filtered off.  The date restrictions need to be part of the join.

Comment: i guess this is causing the trouble.... WHERE form-site_safety_inspection.Type_of_Inspection= "Supervisor Weekly Inspection"   since it will be null for C

Comment: It isn't clear where that restriction belongs, actually.  If the OP only wants to count weekly inspection records, then it belongs in `WHERE`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen any reason why you're using YEARWEEK on Mode 1 over default 0?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for the answer and explanation! I got the result I needed

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just wondering if there's anything I can add to the query so that it returns projects with a count of 0 only?

Comment: Yes, add `HAVING COUNT(f.project) = 0` to the end of the query.